# asp mvc textreader

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a textreader to retrieve data from a text file on a local machine.  I have an upload routine to get the file for the reader to open.

When I run the application locally, it works fine.  When I publish my application to my server, I am getting a Could not find a part of the path error.  I assume this error has to do with permission in that the server cannot read from the local file system, but I don't know the proper way to remedy this.

do I set up the application to impersonate the user?  I know I can't possibly set up each local users machine to allow the iusr account to access it.

Thanks for any thoughts.

UPDATE ****
I ensured that network service is they user for the app pool.  I also ensured that the networkService has access to the local folder that the application resides in.  I am running IIS7, and when I test the site, I am getting the error -

```
The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again
```

I have tried suggestions from various posts, including adding domain\servername$ to the folder to allow access, but nothing seems to work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by first saving the file to the server, and then accessing the server's local file -

```
savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(savedFileName);
```

The following blog helped me out - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/default.aspx?date=2008-06-28

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is IIS 6.5 or higher, the application pool user must have the necessary permission.  By default, this is Network Service, which likely does not.

Comment: necessary permission to what?  the local user file system?  It is defined network service.